# pass a parameter to a node application using POST

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I have the following node application running (relevant part only):

```
app.post("/create_customer_portal_session",async (req, res) => {
    const {customerId} = req.body;
    var session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
        customer: customerId,
        return_url: 'https://****.com/account.php',
    });
    res.send(session);
});
```

It runs fine if I put `customer:'<customer id manually inserted>'` but it doesn't if I try to get the value of customerId from the request.
What am I missing?

On the client side I have:

```
$('#portal').click(function(e){
        var customerId='<?php echo $stripe_customer;?>';
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('https://****.com/store/create_customer_portal_session', {customerId:customerId},function( data ) {
            window.location.href = data.url;
        });         
    });
```

Comment: What's the value of the request.body ?

Comment: maybe it's a dumb question but how do I check it?

Comment: You can just print it with `console.log`

Comment: Is your page actually hosted by a PHP server? You shared backend code that is written in Node(and tagged the question as `express`) so the presence of `<?php echo` confuses me a bit.

Comment: I have a Lamp stack where I perform a Ajax call to a node server. @karllekko

Comment: @karbi the Ajax request remains pending indefinitely, without returning anything. That’s why I am asking

Comment: @LelioFaieta Yes, but I'm assuming it's failing on the call to Stripe (`await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create`). You should still be able to put `console.log(req.body)` before the call to Stripe and see what the value is.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this,

```
   const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
  
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

   app.post("/create_customer_portal_session",async (req, res) => {
      const {customerId} = req.body;
      var session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
        customer: customerId,
        return_url: 'https://****.com/account.php',
      });
      res.send(session);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not using body-parser I had to switch to this code that works:

```
    $('#portal').click(function(e){
        var customerId='<?php echo $stripe_customer;?>';
        e.preventDefault();
        /*$.get('https://thesmartred.com/store/create_customer_portal_session', {customerId:customerId},function( data ) {
            window.location.href = data.url;
        });*/
        fetch("https://***.com/store/create_customer_portal_session", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              customerId: customerId
            })
        }).then(function(result) {
            return result.json();
            window.location.href=result.url;
        });
    });
```

So I can pass the parameters in the body and avoid using body-parser.